# Dynamically set script tag through Grunt based on ENV

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, environment-variables, build-process

During my Grunt build process, I would like to set the script tag in my `index.html` which references the Google Maps API dynamically based on `process.env.NODE_ENV`.
Something like:

```
let googleMapsUrl;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  googleMapsUrl = '//maps.googleaps.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization';
} else {
  googleMapsUrl = `//maps.googleaps.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}v=3.exp&libraries=visualization`;
}
```

My question is how do I then insert `googleMapsUrl` into a script tag in `index.html` like so: `<script src=googleMapsUrl></script>`

Answer (score 1):

There are many options that you could use. From simple, like `grunt-replace` to more advanced ones like `grunt-processhtml`. I will describe the first one as it’s a good option for simple tasks and requires just a simple configuration.

**Using grunt-replace**

`grunt-replace` will search for simple variable definitions like `@@foo` in your source files, and replace those variables with your supplied value or the returning value from a callback.

First install the plugin using `npm install grunt-replace --save-dev`

Then configure the task as follows:

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: 'gmaps',
          replacement: function() {
            var googleMapsUrl;
            if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
              googleMapsUrl = '//maps.googleaps.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=visualization';
            } else {
              googleMapsUrl = '//maps.googleaps.com/maps/api/js?key=' + process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY + 'v=3.exp&libraries=visualization';
            }
            return googleMapsUrl;
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    files: [
      {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        src: ['path/to/your/source/file.html'], dest: 'destination/folder/'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Load the plugin using `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace')` and then add it to your build process.

On your source files just add the defined variable as your script source:

```
<script src="@@gmaps"></script>
```

The task will replace `@@gmaps` with the returning value from the defined callback.

Hope it helps.

More about plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace/blob/master/README.md).